# jQuery function - unintelligible behavior

Tags: jquery

Please see my script here: [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/DmFmM/)

There is a unintelligible behavior which I have noticed.

**Onload `'All'` have 3 option visible - but when you switch to `'logo'` and back to `'all'` we have 4.**

**Why? There should be 4 item in the first tab as well.**

How does the script works:

- onload - I have defined that our `var filterClass = "all";` is all which means to show ONLY `li` with `'all'` class.
- when you select something front the top menu - it is taking it's class and finds `li` with the same class ('li' have multiple classes)
- on every change we run `CreateTabs` function which basically check how many 'li' we have and make them in tabs (4 on every tab).

**Onload Scipt - which controles classes:**

```
$('#portfolio-items li').CreateTabs();   
var filterClass = "all";

$('.portfolio-filter li a').click(function() {


    $('.portfolio-filter > .selected').prop('class', '');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');

    filterClass = $(this).attr('class');

    $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
    $('#portfolio-items li.' + filterClass).show();
    $('#portfolio-items').CreateTabs(filterClass);

});
```

**CreateTabs Script:**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.CreateTabs = function(filterClass) {

    var CoundNumberOfDivs = $('#portfolio-items li:visible').length;
    $('.pagination li a').hide();
    if (CoundNumberOfDivs <= 4) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var num = Math.ceil(CoundNumberOfDivs / 4);
        $('.pagination li a:lt(' + num + ')').show();
        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        if (filterClass === undefined) {
            $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show();
        } else {
            $('#portfolio-items li.' + filterClass + ':lt(4)').show();
        }
    }

};
})(jQuery);
```

**Onload script which controles TABS**

```
$('ul.pagination li a').click(function(event) {
    $('ul.pagination li .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var PI = $('#portfolio-items li' + (filterClass !== undefined) ? '.' + filterClass : '');
    $('#portfolio-items li').hide();


    if ($(this).hasClass('href-1')) {
        PI.slice(0, 4).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-2')) {

        PI.slice(4, 8).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-3')) {
        PI.slice(8, 12).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-4')) {
        PI.slice(12, 16).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-5')) {
        PI.slice(16, 20).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-6')) {
        PI.slice(20, 24).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-7')) {
        PI.slice(24, 28).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-8')) {
        PI.slice(28, 32).show();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('href-9')) {
        PI.slice(32, 36).show();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}).filter(':first').click();
```

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: If you go to Logo page 2, then click to All without going back to page 1 first, this behaviour comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Looking at [the jQuery `.slice()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):</strike>

> <strike>The index is once again zero-based; the range extends up to **but not including** the specified index.</strike>

<strike>So, for example:</strike>

```
if ($(this).hasClass('href-1')) {
    PI.slice(0, 4).show();
}
```

<strike>[should be](http://jsfiddle.net/hAzWW/):</strike>

```
if ($(this).hasClass('href-1')) {
    PI.slice(0, 5).show();
}
```

---

**Edit**

Dennis is absolutely correct, and I cannot count. You were slicing on the wrong thing, due to not being explicit enough with your usage of parentheses:

```
$('#portfolio-items li' +  (filterClass !== undefined) ? '.' + filterClass : '' );
// vs
$('#portfolio-items li' + ((filterClass !== undefined) ? '.' + filterClass : ''));
```

---

[This solves a number of bugs in a number of places](http://jsfiddle.net/PAUR5/), most of which exist because there is a disjoint in how you render "pages" when selecting a category, and when selecting a page number.

- When clicking on a page number (and on page load, due to your `.filter(':first').click()`), this bug would manifest.
- But, when clicking on a category, a *different* logic is invoked — `$('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show()` — which does not exhibit this issue.

I'd consider a stronger high-level design, where the "state" of the interface is tracked in *one* place and re-rendered whenever necessary.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer.  You are using slice to get 5 items from the selection, because the first one is the tab itself.  That is because the selector is getting overwritten due to parenthesis/order of operations: see my answer.

Comment: @Dennis: You're absolutely right. My point regarding the design issues stands.

Comment: @NewUser: In the interests of fairness, you should accept Dennis's answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have parenthesis issues, this should work for you:

```
var PI = $('#portfolio-items li' + ((filterClass !== undefined) ? ('.' + filterClass) : ''));
```

You were previously getting the selector `.all` which was selecting even your tab and messing up your array indices, which can be shown here:

```
var filterClass = "all";
var selector = '#portfolio-items li' + (filterClass !== undefined) ? '.' + filterClass : ''
console.log(selector); //prints ".all", which is clearly not the selector you are going for
```

jsfiddle for good measure: http://jsfiddle.net/DmFmM/60/